# I'm trying to import word doc when program gets to read doc I get error:ASP.NET is not authorized to access the requested resource

Tags: asp.net, windows

I 'm trying  to import a lot of word documents but  i got below error: (I also tried windows app.  and interop.word but i got similar error)

" ASP.NET is not authorized to access the requested resource. Consider granting access rights to the resource to the ASP.NET request identity. ASP.NET has a base process identity (typically {MACHINE}\ASPNET ... "

I red a lot of article and message about this error and I do all of that but it didn't work , even i 'm using visual studio  and also i used iis only  but both situations i got this error. I opened all user , ...\IIS_IUSRS,  IUSR;   all kind of NETWORK SERVICE ... even everyon guest  but in  line Stream readFile below code i got the error  :

```
        destinationFile = destinationFile.Replace("\\" + fileName, "");
        if (ext == ".doc" || ext == ".docx")
        {
            Stream readFile = File.OpenRead(file.Directory.ToString());
            WordDocument doc = null;
            if (ext == ".doc")
```

I appreciate anybody can help me

Thanks  a lot Tomas

Comment: File.OpenRead(file.Directory.ToString()); ???? What is file variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not solve the problem actually all code worked but in a few case I don't know why  just a few docs the line that read the word doc , stooped and there wasn't any exception message  so I replaced the dll. My problem  was solved by Code7248.word_reader.dll, However this dll has its own problem and lock the docs when it read doc , finally i delivered the project.